# Matlab: Newton's method to approximate solution

Tags: matlab, math, matrix

I would like to implement the below system of equations in matlab to approximate the oscillation of a pendulum. While I do understand the initial setup, I do not understand how the "delta" is obtained from dividing two matrices! 
[image]

How does dividing two matrices -G and J yield delta(k) ? I tried the first step in matlab and the result is a 5by5!

How do I solve for delta. An simple example would be great.

MATLAB example:

```
theta= 0.85;
A = (1/h^2).*(diag((-2+sin(theta))*ones(1,n)) + diag(ones(1,n-1),1) + diag(ones(1,n-1),-1));
J= (1/h^2).*(diag((-2+h^2*(cos(theta))^2)*ones(1,n)) + diag(ones(1,n-1),1) + diag(ones(1,n-1),-1));

delta=-A\J
```

I just need to understand this one step, to continue with the iterations.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the math part, `G` is not a matrix, it's a vector.  Or more precisely it's `m` functions, `[G1(theta), G2(theta), ..., Gm(theta)]` that are given by the first line of your math.  The `theta` argument here is also a vector `[theta1, ..., thetam]`.  You want to find the `m` thetas to make the `G` vector all zeros.  That's what's written just before the equation for `J`.

Each of those `Gi` has derivatives with respect to `theta1`, ..., `thetam`.  Those are written in matrix form as `J` in the math.

To solve this nonlinear set of equations with Newton's method, you have a guess for some values for the `theta1`, ..., `thetam` which is called `theta^[k]` in the math.  Evaluate `G` to get a vector of actual numbers (the "residuals").  That's `G(theta^[k])` in the math.

If the function were linear, you could figure out how to exactly correct the guess by adding in the vector `J(theta^[k]) \ -G(theta^[k])`.  That's the Newton update part.  Because the true function is nonlinear, the correction is just an approximation.  After you compute `theta^[k+1]` you repeat the process until you're satisfied with the quality of the answer.

(In general Newton's method isn't guaranteed to converge, but if you're in the neighborhood of a solution and/or things aren't too nonlinear, it's quite fast, doubling the number of correct digits each iteration.)

Edit: An example for `m=5`

```matlab
m=5;
x=linspace(0, 3, m)';
theta=1/5*cos(x)+1/2*sin(x);
alpha=0;
beta=-0.2;
h=0.1;
steps=3;
format short e;
for k=1:steps+1
  theta_minus1=[alpha; theta(1:end-1)];
  theta_plus1=[theta(2:end); beta];
  G=1/h^2*(theta_minus1-2*theta+theta_plus1) + sin(theta);
  fprintf('G=');
  disp(G');
  if k == steps+1
    break
  end
  J=1/h^2*(diag(-2+h^2*cos(theta)) + diag(ones(1, m-1), 1) + diag(ones(1, m-1), -1));
  delta=J\-G;
  theta=theta+delta;
end
```

Comment: looking at the initial guess theta=0.85. How do we update that after the first iteration? the correction is a vector/array, and theta is an integer! That's what I'm trying to comprehend.

Comment: `theta` being a scalar is not consistent with the math part. In the math it's a vector of `m` numbers. (Plus there's some sort of boundary conditions for `theta0` and `theta_m+1`, but presumably the `alpha` and `beta` are given constants.)  I suppose the code could be a broken attempt to do `m=1`, but `n` is pulled out of the hat in that case.

Comment: Could you please right down the first iteration for initial guess theta_init = 1/5cos(x) + 1/2sin(x) ? That's the best way for me to understand this. I am still confused about how to set up the G and J matrices. Thanks.